# Linq XML and complex queries

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to pair the InnerText of two Elements and I finally got the right output, but I'm not sure that it´s efficient. I'm thinking with "from j.." and "from k.." it has to iterate twice through the elements?
Is there a group equivalent to my solution?

```
var query = from i in xdoc.Element("datasource")
                          .Elements("dataobject")
            where (string)i.Attribute("type") == "HMIPage.Generic"

            from j in i.Elements("property")
            where (string)j.Attribute("name") == "PointRefParamName"
            let param = j.Value

            from k in i.Elements("property")
            where (string)k.Attribute("name") == "PointRefPointName"
            let point = k.Value

            select new
            {
                PointName = point,
                ParamName = param                                    
            };

foreach (var tag in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}", tag.PointName, tag.ParamName);
}
```

This is the source file:

```
<datasource version="2">
...
<dataobject id="1" type="HMIPage.Generic" format="propertybag">
    <property name="AddressFlags">0</property>
    <property name="AddressType">0</property>
    <property name="ObjectType">0</property>
    <property name="PointRefFlags">0</property>
    <property name="PointRefParamName">ModeState</property>
    <property name="PointRefParamOffset">0</property>
    <property name="PointRefPointName">01VE05_KMD</property>
    <property name="PresentationType">0</property>
    <property name="SecurityLevel">2</property>
    <property name="UpdatePeriod">0</property>
    <property name="version">1.2</property>
</dataobject>
<dataobject id="2" type="HMIPage.Generic" format="propertybag">
    <property name="AddressFlags">1</property>
    <property name="AddressType">0</property>
    <property name="ObjectType">0</property>
    <property name="PointRefFlags">0</property>
    <property name="PointRefParamName">PointState</property>
    <property name="PointRefParamOffset">0</property>
    <property name="PointRefPointName">01VE05_P1</property>
    <property name="PresentationType">0</property>
    <property name="SecurityLevel">2</property>
    <property name="UpdatePeriod">0</property>
    <property name="version">1.2</property>
</dataobject>
<dataobject id="3" type="HMIPage.PushButton" format="propertybag">
    <property name="Flags">0</property>
    <property name="PBActionType">1</property>
    <property name="RepeatFlag">0</property>
    <property name="SecurityLevel">2</property>
    <property name="StationIndex">0</property>
    <property name="TaskLrn">21</property>
    <property name="TaskParam1">1</property>
    <property name="TaskParam2">223</property>
    <property name="TaskParam3">0</property>
    <property name="TaskParam4">0</property>
    <property name="version">1.2</property>
</dataobject>
...
</datasource>
```

and the output:

01VE05_KMD.ModeState
01VE05_P1.PointState

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = xdoc.Root.Elements("dataobject")
        .Where(x=>x.Attribute("type").Value=="HMIPage.Generic")
        .Elements("property")
        .Where(x=>x.Attribute("name").Value== "PointRefParamName"||x.Attribute("name").Value== "PointRefPointName")
        .Select(x=>x.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks @jyparask. I came up with the same solution somewhere down the line, but it doesn't have the right output. It will take a foreach loop that handles the current and the next item in query to pair them together, since every other item is "PointRefParamName" and every other is "PointRefPointName". I'll vote it up, because I appreciate the effort you put into it, but I'll not mark it as the right solution.